# WPF проблема со 2 формой

Tags: c#, wpf

Добавил вторую форму, подскажите, как в файле App.xaml добавить стиль на вторую форму? P.S. использую Mahapps(Metro).Framework

Comment: При чем здесь файл `App.xaml` ? Он по сути служит связующим звеном, где вы можете к примеру хранить глобальные стили, он не распространяется на одно окно. Ну а как добавить на "вторую форму" - так же, как и на первую, с помощью `XAML` разметки нужного окна.

Comment: `TargetType="local:Window1"` указать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дайте ответ, помечу правильным

Comment: вы хотите разные стили для разных окон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `WPF` файл `App.xaml` является неким связующим звеном всего и вся. Вы там лишь можете создать необходимый стиль (к окну, кнопке и др. элементам), у стилей обычно имеются ключ по которому вы его используете, либо он сразу идёт на все указанные типы (к примеру сразу на все кнопки). То есть из этого файла вы не должны задавать какой то стиль окну или другому элементу, это делается на стороне самого элемента при его инициализации.

Теперь что касается окна. При добавление новых окон они у вас обычно пустые, без стилей, вам нужно всего на всего указать, какой стиль вы хотите использовать на данном объекте указав что то вроде `Style="{StaticResource MyStyleKey}"`.

Советую поискать информацию о том, как создавать и использовать стили (в интернете её много).